# Evaluation of Commutation Relations in Ballentine's book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, commutator, lie-algebra

I'm reading chapter 3 of Leslie Ballentine's book *Quantum Mechanics : A Modern Development* but there are a few derivations I don't understand.

**Question 1 :**
In the middle of page 74, it says

> Antisymmetry of the commutator implies the multiple of identity can be expressed thus : $[J_{\alpha},J_{\beta}]=i\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma} J_{\gamma}+i\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma} b_{\gamma} I$

I can't see the implication. Can anyone give me a more detailed explanation?

**Question 2 :** The next line then says

> The multiple of identity can be removed by the substituion $J_{\alpha}+b_{\alpha}I \to J_{\alpha}$ for $\alpha=1,2,3$.

I don't know what that means. Substitute into where? If I substitute $J_{\alpha}+b_{\alpha}I \to J_{\alpha}$ into $[J_{\alpha},J_{\beta}]=i\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma} J_{\gamma}+i\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \gamma} b_{\gamma} I$ wouldn't I get $[J_{\alpha}+b_{\alpha}I,J_{\beta}+b_{\beta}I]=[J_\alpha,J_\beta]$? This does not tell me anything. How do I eliminate the multiple of identity?

Answer (score 0):

To your first: It’s the antisymmetry of $\epsilon_{ijk}b_k$ that guarantees the
    overall antisymmetry.

To your second: Write $J’_a=J_a+b_a\hat 1$ for clarity, and compute
$$
[J’_a,J’_b]=[J_a,J_b]=i\epsilon_{abc}(J_c+b_c)=i\epsilon_{abc}J’_c
$$

Comment: Thank you ! For the second question, now I see how can we eliminate the multiple of identity. After equation 3.30 on page 74 of the book, it says "this substitution has the effect of replacing the unitary operator $e^{-i\theta J_{\alpha}}$ by $e^{i\theta b_{\alpha}} e^{-i\theta J_{\alpha}}$ " Why does the substitution imply this effect?